# Count distinct records in one column with multiple values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm pretty sure this is an easy question, but I'm having trouble wording it.

I need to count the total number of values in one column based on distinct criteria in another column.

Example:

```
A CD

B ABC 

C AD

D A
```

Would yield:

```
A 3

B 1

C 2

D 2
```

Comment: What is the data type of the second column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be storing lists of things in a string.

But, sometimes one is stuck with this format.  In your example, you seem to have a table with all possible values.  If so you can use a `join`:

```
select e.col1, count(e2.col2)
from example e left join
     example e2
     on charindex(e.col1, e2.col2) > 0
group by e.col1;
```

Note:  this counts rows containing the value rather.  If multiple values appear in a single row, the query is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Now this is an awesome answer!

Comment: this will not consider `AABC` two times. it will count `A` as 1

Comment: @Chad, be careful in production! See my comment.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can do it:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( c1 CHAR(1), c2 VARCHAR(5) )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'A', 'CD' ),
        ( 'B', 'ABC' ),
        ( 'C', 'AD' ),
        ( 'D', 'A' )


SELECT  t.c1 ,
        SUM(count) AS count
FROM    @t t
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    LEN(c2) - LEN(REPLACE(c2, t.c1, '')) AS count
                      FROM      @t
                      WHERE     c2 LIKE '%' + t.c1 + '%'
                    ) ca
GROUP BY t.c1
```

Comment: I guess your answer is the most accurate for generic scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming table is called yourtable and fields are like soo.

```
fielda fieldb
A      CD
B      ABC 
C      AD
D      A
```

Code

```
SELECT a.fielda, (SELECT COUNT(b.fieldb)
FROM yourtable b
WHERE b.fieldb LIKE '%a.fielda%' AND b.fielda = a.fielda) AS counter
FROM yourtable a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery with `LIKE`

**Sample Data**

```
with cte(a,b) as 
(
select 'A','CD'
union all select 'B','ABC' 
union all select'C','AD'
union all select'D','A'
)
```

**Query**

```
select a,(select count(*) from cte c2 where b like '%' + c1.a +'%')
from cte c1
group by a
```

**Output**

```
A   3
B   1
C   2
D   2
```

Comment: this will not consider `AABC` two times. it will count `A` as 1.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - Yes, you are correct, however not sure if that is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated sub-query when counting. Use `LIKE` to find rows to find rows to count.

```
select t1.col1, (select count(*) from tablename t2
                 where t2.col2 like '%' || t1.col1 ||'%')
from tablename t1
```

`||` is ANSI SQL concatenation. Some products use `concat()`, or `+` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a self join there but the trick would be to use a pattern match on the join rather than an equi-join...

```
create table x1(c1 char(1) primary key, c2 varchar(5) not null); 

select x1.c1, count(*) 
  from x1 x1 
  join x1 x2 on x2.c2 like '%' || x1.c1 || '%' 
  group by x1.c1 
  order by 1;
```